# Unable to run tokyo tyrant due to server socket open error

Tags: tokyo-tyrant

I have installed tokyo tyrant interface to tokyo cabinet. But whenever I tried to run the tyrant it is throwing server socket error. That is "ttopenservsock failed"

Any solution?